# Javascript table cells value inside on clicked table cells value

Tags: javascript

I created a table, and inside this table I added `onclick` function to a specific cell, and it's work. But when I want to get a value of a specific cell inside the on clicked cell it dosen't work. It gives me the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

This is my code:

```
    var rIndex=document.getElementById("tablewithdrawal");
    //select the row
    function selectedRowToInput()
    {

    for(var i = 0; i < tablewithdrawal.rows.length; i++)
    {
        tablewithdrawal.rows[i].cells[13].onclick = function()
        {
        // get the seected row index




        // get the seected row index

          accountnumercell=this.cells[0].innerHTML;
        alert(accountnumercell);



        };
```

Comment: `this.cells` is not defined.. what do you think `this` is?

Comment: could you help me to understand please i'm trying to learn

Comment: Can you add an example of the table to show what a "cell inside a cell" means?

Comment: ok i think my explanation is kinda confusing lets say i have 3 rows and when i click on the third row it should show me the value of the first row .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

```
accountnumercell=this.cells[0].innerHTML;
```

"this" is bound to the cell you are attaching the listener to.

In case you want this to refer to the row of the cell, you should do something like

```
tablewithdrawal.rows[i].cells[13].onclick = (function()
    accountnumercell=this.cells[0].innerHTML;
    alert(accountnumercell);
).bind(tablewithdrawal.rows[i]);
```

By the way, the onclick method is deprecated and should no more be used in current version on JavaScript. In turn, you could write it like

```
function selectedRowToInput() {
  for (let i = 0; i < tablewithdrawal.rows.length; i++) {
    let row = tablewithdrawal.rows[i];

    row.cells[13].addEventListener('click', () => {
        accountnumercell = row.cells[0].innerHTML;
        alert(accountnumercell);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: btw thank you for the help . and i tried the second method but when i click on it it show me the alert more the one time

Comment: This happens because you call selectedRowToInput more than one time. You'll get one alert for each listener you attach. Are you sure you need to call that function many times?

Answer (score 0):

The error you encounter occurs because `this` refers to `tablewithdrawal.rows[i].cells[13]` inside your event handler. Therefore, `this.cells[0]` doesn't make sense, because it means you're trying to get `tablewithdrawal.rows[i].cells[13].cells[0]`, which doesn't exist.

Now, based on what you have provided in your question, it seems to me that you're trying to show the content of the first cell of the row, whose 14th cell you've clicked. Correct me if I'm wrong.

**Solution 1:**

What you need to use instead of `this` is the row, namely `tablewithdrawal.rows[i]`, so try caching that inside the loop and using it inside your event handler to access the first cell of the row.

```
/* Iterate over every row of the table. */
for (let i = 0; i < tablewithdrawal.rows.length; i++) {
  /* Cache the current row. */
  let row = tablewithdrawal.rows[i];

  /* Set the 'click' event of the 14th cell. */
  row.cells[13].onclick = function() {
    /* Alert the content of the row's 1st cell. */
    alert(row.cells[0].innerHTML);
  };
}
```

**Solution 2:**

Alternatively, as another answer has mentioned, you can use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to pass a custom context to the event handler, thus enabling you to keep your code inside it intact.

```
/* Iterate over every row of the table. */
for (let i = 0; i < tablewithdrawal.rows.length; i++) {
  /* Cache the current row. */
  let row = tablewithdrawal.rows[i];

  /* Set the 'click' event of the 14th cell. */
  row.cells[13].onclick = function() {
    /* Alert the content of the row's 1st cell. */
    alert(this.cells[0].innerHTML);
  }.bind(row);
}
```

**Snippet:**

```js
/* Find the table. */
var tablewithdrawal = document.querySelector("table");

/* Iterate over every row of the table. */
for (let i = 0; i < tablewithdrawal.rows.length; i++) {
  /* Cache the current row. */
  let row = tablewithdrawal.rows[i];

  /* Set the 'click' event of the 14th cell. */
  row.cells[13].onclick = function() {
    /* Alert the content of the row's 1st cell. */
    alert(row.cells[0].innerHTML);
  };
}
```

```css
table td {
  font-size: .8125em;
  padding: .5em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<!-- Sample table -->
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>R0 C0</td>
    <td>R0 C1</td>
    <td>R0 C2</td>
    <td>R0 C3</td>
    <td>R0 C4</td>
    <td>R0 C5</td>
    <td>R0 C6</td>
    <td>R0 C7</td>
    <td>R0 C8</td>
    <td>R0 C9</td>
    <td>R0 C10</td>
    <td>R0 C11</td>
    <td>R0 C12</td>
    <td>R0 C13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>R1 C0</td>
    <td>R1 C1</td>
    <td>R1 C2</td>
    <td>R1 C3</td>
    <td>R1 C4</td>
    <td>R1 C5</td>
    <td>R1 C6</td>
    <td>R1 C7</td>
    <td>R1 C8</td>
    <td>R1 C9</td>
    <td>R1 C10</td>
    <td>R1 C11</td>
    <td>R1 C12</td>
    <td>R1 C13</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```